# Output stdio and stderr from pytest.main()

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to get the output from a test that you run via pytest, using the call to main?

```
string = "-x mytests.py"
pytest.main(string)
print(????????)
```

If this was a process I could get the output using `communicate()` but I can't find the equivalent for pytest when running it as function from Python3, instead than run it as standalone from terminal.

EDIT:
I did try to use `sys.stdout` but it didn't work either...I am fundamentally stuck since I can't get the pytest output in any way; beside in my output IDE window. Any suggestion or workaround would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to a different question, which was mentioning how to redirect the whole `stdout` stream.

I did not find a way to print only pytest messages; but I can redirect stdio from the output on screen, in a string variable in this way:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

def myfunctionThatDoesSomething():

    # Save the original stream output, the console basically
    original_output = sys.stdout
    # Assign StringIO so the output is not sent anymore to the console
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    # Run your Pytest test
    pytest.main(script_name)
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    # close the stream and reset stdout to the original value (console)
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = original_output

    # Do whatever you want with the output
    print(output.upper())
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for a way to retrieve data from their pytest output, in the meantime that a better solution to get just the pytest output in a variable is found.

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.4 (per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=context#contextlib.redirect_stdout)), there is an easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

temp_stdout = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(temp_stdout):
    result = pytest.main(sys.argv)
stdout_str = temp_stdout.getvalue()
# or whatever you want to do with it
print(stdout_str.upper())
```